# Search results web part changes the page title

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-search

I have added a search results web part along with a few other web parts on the home page of a SharePoint 2013 on-premise site. When you put a keyword in the search box and click search icon, it changes the page title to "Search Results: `<keyword>`". 
[image]

This wouldn't be a problem on the search page but on a page it is not good to change the page title. How do we keep this from happening?
I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!